# How to call the Triggers in user deefined way?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I created the Employee table which contains EmpNo,EName,EDesignation as its fields.Also i created the 3 Triggers namely **Trigger_1,Trigger_2 and Trigger_3**.All the Triggers are **Statement level triggers** and fired **after** the update done in the table.Now i want the following orders in which the triggers are going to fired when the update statement is executed.

The Order is

**Trigger_3,
Trigger_1,
Trigger_2**

Can anyone tell me the way to fire the trigger events in userdefined way?I m using Oracle 9i

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trigger Evaluation Order

Quote from Oracle documentation:

> Although any trigger can run a
>   sequence of operations either in-line
>   or by calling procedures, using
>   multiple triggers of the same type
>   enhances database administration by
>   permitting the modular installation of
>   applications that have triggers on the
>   same tables.
>
> Oracle Database executes all triggers
>   of the same type before executing
>   triggers of a different type. If you
>   have multiple triggers of the same
>   type on a single table, then Oracle
>   Database chooses an arbitrary order to
>   execute these triggers.
>
> Each subsequent trigger sees the
>   changes made by the previously fired
>   triggers. Each trigger can see the old
>   and new values. The old values are the
>   original values, and the new values
>   are the current values, as set by the
>   most recently fired UPDATE or INSERT
>   trigger.
>
> To ensure that multiple triggered
>   actions occur in a specific order, you
>   must consolidate these actions into a
>   single trigger (for example, by having
>   the trigger call a series of
>   procedures).

see also http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm

Answer (score 0):

Have one trigger with the contents of the three.

If you cannot, for reasons for modularization, reusability..., create three stored procedures and call these one by one in the single trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to 11g and you can define [trigger execution order](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/TriggerEnhancements_11gR1.php)